# Hide visual studio function toolbar

Tags: visual-studio-2010

How can I hide this [toolbar](http://s019.radikal.ru/i604/1211/76/45d2828ff407.png)? Tried to search, but I don't even know how to name it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's well hidden! :)

You can hide it under `Tools > Options > Text Editor > All Languages (Or a specific language) > General > Navigation Bar`

[image: Hide Navigation Bar]